# MongoDB - what should I index

Tags: mongodb, database-design, mongoose

I have a Collection in my database that stores applications:

```
{
  _id: <ObjectId>, //MongoDB's default id
  public_key: "abcde12345", //10 character string
  private_key: "abcdefg1234567", //14 character string
  name: "Cool App",
  desc: "This is a cool app",
  calls: 145
}
```

I will need to search for applications using `public_key` and `private_key` and didn't want to "blindly" add indexes for both in my schema without really understanding if they should be indexed or not.

Could someone suggest which fields should have indexes please?

Answer (score 0):

Which parts you index depends solely on which find-queries are most important. These are usually those which are executed most frequently.

When your application frequently searches for `public_key` and `private_key` these are good candidates for indexing. When you always search for exact values, you should define them as hashed indexes. On large collections they are much faster than sorted indexes, but don't allow anything but searching by exact value.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I would typically create an index (via Mongoosejs) like this `{ type: String, index: true }` - how do I define them as hashed because I will search for exact values?

Comment: @tommyd456: see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-hashed/#index-type-hashed - not sure how to do it w/ mongoose, but I guess google will tell